# How to Display anchor elements Inline which are in a list element in dropdown-menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my Html code

```html
<li ng-show="authentication.isAuth" ng-repeat="menu in menuList" class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{menu.title}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="li in menu.subMenuList">
         <a href="{{li.state}}">{{li.title}} </a>
         <a class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" href="{{li.stateh}}"></a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

[image: Below is how my Navbar looks]

I want the edit icon to be adjacent to F/R production Report. Not below Production Report.

P.S. I tried display: inline-block; display: inline; but both are not working.

Comment: Will this help `dropdown-menu li { white-space: nowrap`  } ... or `display: flex;` ?

Comment: display: flex; worked. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you triend to simply place the  tag inside the previous  tag?

```html
<li ng-show="authentication.isAuth" ng-repeat="menu in menuList" class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{menu.title}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="li in menu.subMenuList">
         <a href="{{li.state}}">{{li.title}} <a class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" href="{{li.stateh}}"></a> </a>      
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: The Icon has a separate reference(<a class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" href="{{li.stateh}}">). So, If I placed inside previous tag then both will have same reference.